# Catch error inside Firestore on_snapshot from the outer scope

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, python-asyncio, try-except

I'm writing a python program, when it catches any error, it will reset everything and restart itself.

It goes like this

```
async def main_loop():
    while True:
        try:
            await main()
        except:
            stop_everything()
            reset_everything()
        await asyncio.sleep(60)

asyncio.run(main_loop())
```

Part of the main program is to watch a Firestore collection.

```
def collection_changed(docs, changes, time):
    # Error can possibly happen here.
    raise RuntimeError("Something wrong.")

async def main():
    col_ref.on_snapshot(collection_changed)
    await some_forever_task()
```

The error in `collection_changed` will not be caught by the `try-except` block, because `on_snapshot` runs in the background, kind of like `asyncio.create_task`.

But in the case of `asyncio.create_task`, I can do `task = asyncio.create_task(...)` and then `await task`. This way, error in the task will be caught.

I tried `watch = col_ref.on_snapshot(...)`, but I can't `await watch`.

So how can I catch error that happens inside `on_snapshot` from the outer scope?

Answer (score 0):

In Python, there is no easy way of catching the errors they throw because they throw them in a separate thread. I have found an alternative method to detect the listener error and restart the listener after a server side closes.

Firebase listeners keep track of a private variable `_closed` that becomes **true** if ever the connection gets closed for any reason. Therefore, by checking that, we can restart our listener or do any function that we want to.

Take a look at this e.g:

```
def on_snapshot(doc_snapshot, changes, read_time):
    for doc in doc_snapshot:
        print(f'Received document snapshot: {doc.id}')

doc_ref = db.collection(u'cities').document(u'SF')

# Watch the document
doc_watch = doc_ref.on_snapshot(on_snapshot)

try:
  while(True):
    if doc_watch._closed:
      print('closed')
    # code here (restart/reset)
except Exception as err:
  print(err)
  print("Error occurred at " + str(time.ctime()))
  traceback.print_exc()
```

The code above should detect if the listener is closed for any reason, then you may want what you want if it is being detected as `closed`. I hope that this sample snippet helps you with what you want to achieve.